# debian apt cant find openjdk-8-jdk

Tags: java, linux, debian, apt, openjdk-8

im trying to install openjdk-8-jdk as suggested [here](https://openjdk.java.net/install/) with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

but apt dosnt find the package. i did find it at [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/amd64/java/openjdk-8-jdk) manualy and tried to tell apt to also load from there, as suggested on the [mirrors page](https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/amd64/openjdk-8-jdk/download) of that package by adding the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main
```

but apt still cant find the package. i also tried to change the

- url to http://deb.debian.org/debian
- sid to buster or buster-backports
- main to unstable, non-free, contrib (or a list of some or all of those)
- combinations of all of the above

still no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main`
2. install openjdk8

   ```
   //Update the repositories<br/>
   $ sudo apt-get update<br/>
   $ sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
   ```

In fact, I think it is better to search for your question first before ask.

[How to install openjdk-8-jdk on Debian 10 (Buster)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031649/how-to-install-openjdk-8-jdk-on-debian-10-buster)

Comment: You beat me to it.  It sounds like the OP forgot to run `apt-get update` after editing /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: I would be glad if it would help.

Comment: WARNING !!! do not add an unstable repository on a production server !!!!!