# Install Java OpenJDK 8 on Debian 11 (Bullseye)

Tags: java

How to install Java OpenJDK 8 in 2023?

Have tried to follow all the answers but none of them work

[How to install openjdk-8-jdk on Debian 10 (Buster)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031649/how-to-install-openjdk-8-jdk-on-debian-10-buster)

And I remember to change the codename to `bullseye` when adding the repository

example

```
echo "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security $(lsb_release -cs)/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update
```

Install

```
# apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk
```

I'm not an expert in linux and prefer `apt-get install` to handle dependencies etc.

Comment: That would probably be a better fit on https://serverfault.com/ as this is not about programing but software install

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699507/how-can-i-install-java-8-on-debian-11-bullseye

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i'm not an expert in linux so prefer `apt-get install`

Comment: I remove my comment not to give duplicate info

Comment: Install on which operating system and version? It is not clear why the current year is relevant.

Comment: @aled in the headline it says `Debian 11 Bullseye`

Comment: @jhamon There's a close reason for exactly that case (hint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no more support of openJDK-8 so you need to use another JDK like correto, Eclipse Temurin... register there apt repo and install it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/generic-linux-install.html

https://adoptium.net/installation/linux/

Comment: If using the amazon solution to install `Java OpenJDK 8` you have to install `apt-get install -y java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-jdk` ??

Comment: yes but it's not OpenJDK 8, it's a JDK 8 compliante build by amazon.